# Display a message if worksheet names are not pre-spescified ones?

Tags: vba, excel

I need to keep "CMGLT", "CMCLT" and "CMGPD" on my workbook. If any other worksheets exists in the workbook I need to display a message. How can I do this?

Comment: Are those the names you need?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
For i=1 to Sheets.Count

  If Sheets(i).Name <> "CMGLT" And Sheets(i).Name <> "CMCLT" And Sheets(i).Name <> "CMGPD" then
    MsgBox Sheets(i).Name
  End if

Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query the SheetNames in WorkBook Open event and if any SheetName other than the desired ones is found, show a messagebox (or do whatever you want to do).

Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the VBA Code Editor. Then double-click on `ThisWorkBook` in Project window to open the workbook code, and paste this code there.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Select Case ws.Name
        Case "CMGLT", "CMCLT", "CMGPD"      '-- put all valid sheet names here.
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Invalid sheets in this workbook!", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```